# Configuration database changes while creating SharePoint web application

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

While creating a SharePoint web application

What is happening at the configuration database?

What are the files that will be created?

I want to know the background process?

Can you please any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Creates a unique entry in SharePoint configuration DB for the Web App and assign GUID to that entry;
- Create and configures a Web application in IIS
- Creates a root folder to store the Web application pages and associated resources;
- Creates and configures an IIS application pool;
- Configures authentication protocol and encryption settings;
- Assign a Default alternate access mapping for the Web app;
- Creates the first content database for the Web application;
- Associate a search service with the Web application;
- Assign a name to the Web application that appears in the Web application list in SharePoint Central Administration;
- Assign general settings to the Web application, such as maximum file upload size and default time zone;

Reference: [Link1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17955.sharepoint-2010-what-happens-internally-when-a-web-application-is-created.aspx)

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it solves your query